# How to get an element By ID inside React.Fragment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to catch an element using an ID in React, but I could not.

```
render() {
  //Looping through all menus
  let menuOptions = this.props.menuLists.map(menuList => {
    return (
      <li className="nav-item active" key={menuList.name}>
        <a className="nav-link" href={menuList.anchorLink}>
          {menuList.name}
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id="animSec">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I want to call the **myCanvas** ID.

I tried by `this.refs`, but it's sent me *undefined*. I also tried `react-dom`:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myCanvas);
```

but get nothing. I call `findDOMNode` on the constructor first and I tried `componentDidMount` but get nothing.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele)

Comment: did u people read the question or just wait to mark it ..... i mention i tried on stack overflow ans but that not give me any solution. plz read first then mark  it as a  duplicate.

Comment: @sayalok Please define a ref on canvas to access it via a ref. Thats the reason its not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to retrieve the ID:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.canvas = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.canvas.id) // gives you "myCanvas"
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="animSec">
          <canvas id="myCanvas" ref={c => {this.canvas = c}}></canvas>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

---

*alternatively*, for React v16.3+, you can use [createRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.canvas = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.canvas.current.id) // gives you "myCanvas"
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="animSec">
          <canvas id="myCanvas" ref={this.canvas}></canvas>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Comment: thanks it did work. but can u explain a bit this line c => {this.canvas = c} why do i have to call the fun and pass the element through it ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs
Firstly, understand that the lifecycle is like this: constructor -> render -> componentDidMount (cdm). Before mounting the component, constructor runs and declared `canvas` variable, then after the first render, we store <canvas> in `this.canvas` using ref API, then we can access it in CDM.

Comment: After v16.3, there is a new createRef() method: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs I will update the answer with this newer method.

Comment: thanks a lot . yeah that was the real reason . i didnt maintain lifecycle thing while i coding

Comment: glad it worked out for you. do accept my answer if it helps, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a ref in your constructor as this.canvasRef = React.createRef()
and apply it to your canvas as

```
<React.Fragment> 
  <div id="animSec">
    <canvas ref={this.canvasRef}></canvas>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

You should be able to access the element directly. You can console log or check your dev tools to view the ref value. And (to my best knowledge), it's best practice to use Refs compared to querySelectors in React. You might also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578237/get-a-reference-to-a-canvas-element-from-its-context) to see if you can work around with a method on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `document.getElementById('myCanvas')` in a custom function or any life cycle method to target the desired element.

Note that this doesn't work if you're doing SSR with a framework like next.js because there is no document object in the server.

Comment: its send me undefined error 
        Cannot read property 'width' of null

Comment: Try using it in `componentDidMount` and to get the width use clientWidth. I tried it in the `componentDidMount` and console logged the output of `document.querySelector('#myCanvas')`

Comment: console.log(document.querySelector('#myCanvas')); inside componentDidMount no return
inside constructor null

Comment: That's odd. It worked for me. Try making a new component with only the `<React.Fragment>
     <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</React.Fragment>`
and try to use the `document.querySelector('#myCanvas')` in componentDidMount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185535/discussion-between-sayalok-and-muljayan).